# Vmware-iso builder not creating vmware.log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packer, hashicorp-packer

I have been trying with very basic template to create vmware specific image from existing Ubuntu ISO image but the packer build is failing with below error and I am not able to find the reason behind it.

```
$ packer build -on-error=ask ubuntu_vmware.json
vmware-iso: output will be in this color.

==> vmware-iso: Retrieving ISO
==> vmware-iso: Trying ../ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso
==> vmware-iso: Trying ../ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso?checksum=md5%3Aeeabb7996e94b2f0a6eaf73f8943d19f
==> vmware-iso: ../ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso?checksum=md5%3Aeeabb7996e94b2f0a6eaf73f8943d19f => /home/user/ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso
==> vmware-iso: Configuring output and export directories...
==> vmware-iso: Creating required virtual machine disks
==> vmware-iso: Building and writing VMX file
==> vmware-iso: Starting virtual machine...
    vmware-iso: The VM will be run headless, without a GUI. If you want to
    vmware-iso: view the screen of the VM, connect via VNC with the password "yqPTl0YR" to
    vmware-iso: vnc://127.0.0.1:5974
==> vmware-iso: Error starting VM: VMware error: Error: The operation was canceled
==> vmware-iso: Error starting VM: VMware error: Error: The operation was canceled
==> vmware-iso: Step "StepRun" failed
==> vmware-iso: [c] Clean up and exit, [a] abort without cleanup, or [r] retry step (build may fail even if retry succeeds)?
```

I do see that the output directory has vmdk, vmx files generated but not the log vmware.log file, previously I remember this file used to get created and has details about the errors.

```
$ ls ubuntu-vware-new/
disk-s001.vmdk  disk-s003.vmdk  disk-s005.vmdk  disk-s007.vmdk  disk-s009.vmdk  disk.vmdk                   packer-vmware-example.vmx
disk-s002.vmdk  disk-s004.vmdk  disk-s006.vmdk  disk-s008.vmdk  disk-s010.vmdk  packer-vmware-example.vmsd  packer-vmware-example.vmxf
```

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "iso_url": "../ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "md5:eeabb7996e94b2f0a6eaf73f8943d19f",
      "guest_os_type": "ubuntu-64",
      "headless": "true",
      "communicator": "ssh",
      "ssh_username": "packer",
      "ssh_password": "packer",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "20m",
      "output_directory": "ubuntu-vware-new",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "vm_name": "packer-vmware-example",
      "vmx_data": {
        "memsize": "2048",
        "numvcpus": "2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "echo 'Hello, Packer!'"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

vmware-workstation version 16.1.0.17198959 is installed.

am I missing something here ?

Comment: I dont see this problem with workstation version 17. It generates vmware.log file which helps debugging issue further.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/vmware/iso does not mention a creation of such a log file.

You could maybe:

- extract logs from the actual build process from within the build
- or use packer's logs

for further analysis